# Inline C not working in Varnish-4.0.3

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I am working with varnish-4.0.3 and `vcc_allow_inline_c` is `off` by default. What I have done is:

```
varnishadm 
200        
-----------------------------
Varnish Cache CLI 1.0
-----------------------------
Linux,3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64,x86_64,-sfile,-sfile,-sfile,-smalloc,-hcritbit
varnish-4.0.3 revision b8c4a34

Type 'help' for command list.
Type 'quit' to close CLI session.

param.show vcc_allow_inline_c
200
vcc_allow_inline_c         on [bool]
```

And, in default.vcl,

```
C{
  #include <stdio.h>
}C
```

But, it's not working, systemd isn't starting properly.

```
varnishd[28929]: Message from VCC-compiler:
varnishd[28929]: Inline-C not allowed
varnishd[28929]: ('input' Line 6 Pos 1)
varnishd[28929]: C{
varnishd[28929]: ##
varnishd[28929]: Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2
varnishd[28929]: VCL compilation failed
```

I also tried using `DAEMON_OPTS="-p vcc_allow_inline_c=on"`, but that didn't work either.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Hello, did you found a fix ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are modifying the wrong configuration file?

With systemd the startup arguments are specified in the `varnish.service` file, not `/etc/default/varnish` as previously.

Answer (score 0):

If you run ps -ef|grep varnishd - you should see if that option is set or not.

Comment: I got the same issue, if I check ps -ef, I can see varnishd with -p vcc_allow_inline_c=on

Comment: Does your VCL with the inline C compile or does it give errors? That should be your first step in debugging this.